# Symfony4 kernel event performing redirects and dependant on user

Tags: php, symfony, events, symfony4

I want to check something from user entity on every request, and if some conditions are met I want to perform redirect. Have tried this:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
            ['watcher', 0],
        ]
    ];
}

public function watcher(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) return;

    /** @var Request $request */
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    echo "User: " . $request->getUser();
    exit();
}
```

but $request->getUser() returns null

Any suggestions how to get user in kernel events ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$request->getUser()` does **not** return a user object that has been authenticated by the security component, but rather the username part of the HTTP basic auth.

For example, if you request http://username:password@example.com/ then `$request->getUser()` will contain `"username"`.

To get the user object you have to inject the `security.token_storage` service into your event subscriber and then call `$tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()`.

Note that both `getToken()` and `getUser()` can return `null`, so you should check both first. Have a look at [the `getUser()` implementation in Symfony's `ControllerTrait`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.0/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php#L352) on how best to do that.

Comment: Perfect, didnt knew that request user states for http auth. Thanks!